# Repinning messages in chat is weird

Tags: support, chat, chat-pins

[image: chat error messages: "You cannot star your own messages", "You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator"]

What does the above message mean? Did the pin expire? Or did a mod manually clear the pin on it? Or when the pin expires, [Community](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) removes it automatically?

Also, could the "vote" part be changed to whatever it should be? For example:

> You have already pinned this message, but the pin was cleared by a moderator

> You have already starred this message, but the star was cleared by a moderator